# whether to use arraylist or some other collection while iterating

Tags: java, collections

I am having two profiles say `SignProfile` and `ValidationProfile`. These profiles can be more than 1, say

```
SignProfile.size >1 and  ValidationProfile.size>1
```

Now there is a piece of code which I have to execute whenever `SignProfile` and `ValidationProfile` are not `null` and I need to loop through these profiles too if they are more than one for both Sign and Validation.

I am using

```
List<SignProfile> SP = new ArrayList<>;
List<ValidationProfile> Vali = new ArrayList<>;
while SP_interator.hasnext
{
    while Vali_interator.hasnext
    {
        // do something
    }
    // Piece of code
}
```

Now the problem I am facing is that sometimes SignProfile comes `null`, but ValidationProfile is not `null`. So as per above code, the intended piece of code is not executed.

Could someone please guide me? Shall I use some other collection?

Comment: why you do in a nested loop, how are they related?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
if (signProfiles != null && validationProfiles != null) {

    for (SignProfile signProfile : signProfiles) {
        //do something with signProfile
    }

    for (ValidationProfile validationProfile : validationProfiles) {
        //do something with validationProfile
    }
}
```

Or the nested version...

```
if (signProfiles != null && validationProfiles != null) {

    for (SignProfile signProfile : signProfiles) {
        //do something with signProfile

        for (ValidationProfile validationProfile : validationProfiles) {
        //do something with validationProfile, and signProfile?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Java 5 or higher, you can use the foreach syntax:

```
List<SignProfile> signProfileList = new ArrayList<>;
List<ValidationProfile> validationProfileList = new ArrayList<>;

if(signProfileList != null) {
  for(SignProfile sp : signProfileList) {
    // you can work with the sp variable here, which represents the current item from signProfileList
    if(validationProfileList != null) {
      for(ValidationProfile vp : validationProfileList) {
        // you can work with vp variable here, which represents the current item from validationProfileList
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: I've renamed some of your variables to make the code a little clearer.

By the way, are you sure you want these nested?  They don't seem to relate to eachother.